# Circular Count Down Timer Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get the "00" off my count down when the time is up?

```
Widget _buildTimer() {
    return CircularCountDownTimer(
      fillColor: Colors.red,
      color: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: null,
      duration: _data[_currentIndex].duration,
      controller: _controller,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
      strokeWidth: 10.0,
      strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 33.0, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textFormat: CountdownTextFormat.SS,
      isReverse: true,
      isReverseAnimation: true,
      isTimerTextShown: true,
      autoStart: true,
    );
  }
```

When the time runs out it looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O947k.gif)

Can anyone in help?

Comment: I guess You should change textformat to CountdownTextFormat.S. Check out the [source code](https://github.com/MuhammadUsamaSiddiqui/circular_countdown_timer/blob/80981ef591e8355d2400a57803b8e40360a40237/lib/circular_countdown_timer.dart#L114)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this https://pub.dev/packages/circular_countdown_timer

In that case, you need to have a variable controlling the state of the text visibility. Then you can change this in the onComplete callback.

```
  bool isTimerShown = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CircularCountDownTimer(
        fillColor: Colors.red,
        backgroundColor: null,
        duration: 3,
        controller: CountDownController(),
        width: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width / 4,
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height / 4,
        strokeWidth: 10.0,
        strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 33.0,
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        textFormat: CountdownTextFormat.SS,
        isReverse: true,
        isReverseAnimation: true,
        isTimerTextShown: isTimerShown,
        autoStart: true,
        ringColor: Colors.white,
        onComplete: () =>
            setState(() {
              isTimerShown = false;
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```